# PHP: Reformatting Array

Tags: php, arrays

Help me to reformat my array which is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [sampleArr] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

This is my array need to be reformat like in the above array:

```
Array
(
    [sampleArr] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [id2] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: array with same key is not possible.

Comment: The second array is not valid, you cannot have the same key multiple times. However, `[sampleArr] => Array(0 => 1, 1 => 2)` would work

Comment: sorry i just forgot to notice the same key but i changed it already

Answer (score 0):

may be you can looping again your array like this.

```
$data['sampleArr'] = [];
foreach($data['sampleArr'] as $key => $value) {
   $k = !empty($key) ? $key : "";
   $format['sampleArr'][$value['id'].$k] = $value['id'];
}
```